# In Excel, can I create a name that refers to cells that aren't tied to one worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells, named-ranges

This isn't a question about the scope of names. It's a question about specifying the cells in a name.

Imagine I've created a name `=A1+B2`.

That gets hard-coded by Excel into `Sheet1!A1+Sheet1!B2`. But I don't want those cells to be tied to `Sheet1`.

I want to use this name on multiple worksheets. If I use this name in Sheet1, I want the name to be equivalent to `Sheet1!A1+Sheet1!B2`. But if I use this name in Sheet2, I want it to be equivalent to `Sheet2!A1+Sheet2!B2`.

Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: Mark, are you talking about Multi Sheet reference. Like if I use data range across the sheet with function as named range?

Answer (score 0):

edit: this probably won't work with Named Ranges.

You can use this formula (found on [extendoffice.com](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2618-excel-reference-tab-name.html)) to get the current sheet name (note that the file must be saved first, this will not work on a new Blank workbook):

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)
```

Combine that with an `INDIRECT` to get the value of `A1`:

```
=INDIRECT(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)&"!A1")
```

And then the final formula to combine your `A1` and `B2`:

```
=INDIRECT(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)&"!A1")+INDIRECT(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)&"!B2")
```